# Display Image on mouse-on hover

Tags: javascript, image, jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, html.actionlink

I am having this application where I need to have something like, when we bring the mouse over an employee's name, which is an actionlink , it is suppose to show the employee's image.
I am trying to do so using MVC, but am till far unable to do so.
Please can anyone help me out in this..
Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 1):

This is a JavaScript thing, *not* an ASP.NET MVC thing. You'll take one of two approaches:

1. Put the image on page at load, but give it a class or otherwise style it to be hidden initially. Then you'll just need to add an JS event handler for the mouseover event of your links that will cause the image to display.
2. Again, you'll use a JS event handler tied to the mouseover event of your links, but you send an AJAX request for the image URL and then dynamically insert the image into the page based on the response. This is kind of overkill for something this simple though.

#1 is really the best way to go for this use case, and there's probably around 10 million articles, blog posts, tutorials, etc. online regarding hiding and showing content based on a JS event. Google your heart out.